# How to find adjacent values in a dataframe given x and y values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with a sequence along an x and y axis. I would like to show adjacency in values.

For example, with the following data frame:

| x | y | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | red |
| 1 | 0 | pink |
| 2 | 0 | green |
| 3 | 0 | blue |
| 0 | 1 | yellow |
| 1 | 1 | orange |
| 2 | 1 | blue |
| 3 | 1 | purple |

Visually:

[image]

The x column follows along 0-3 as the y values moves up the y axis 0-1. I would like to show adjacency but am unsure of the proper formatting - Desired outcome shown below with a maximum of 3 adjacent values

| x | y | value | adjacent_1 | adjacent_2 | adjacent_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | red | pink | yellow | NA |
| 1 | 0 | pink | red | green | orange |
| 2 | 0 | green | pink | blue | blue |
| 3 | 0 | blue | purple | green | NA |
| 0 | 1 | yellow | red | orange | NA |
| 1 | 1 | orange | yellow | pink | blue |
| 2 | 1 | blue | orange | green | purple |
| 3 | 1 | purple | blue | blue | NA |

I am able to get results with something like the following, but it only repeats over the first request of x values and takes quite a while to run on a larger df:

```py
max_x = df['x'].max()
for i in range(max_x):
    df['adjacent_value_1'].iloc[i] = df['value'].iloc[i-1]
    test.append(df.copy())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
        "y": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "value": ["red", "pink", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "blue", "purple"],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to it:

```py
# Find adjacent values
for i, t in enumerate([(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]):
    df[f"adjacent_{i}"] = df.apply(
        lambda df_: df.loc[
            (df["x"] == df_["x"] + t[0]) & (df["y"] == df_["y"] + t[1]), "value"
        ].values,
        axis=1,
    )

# Get values and add them to a list in temporary column
for col in df.columns:
    if not col.startswith("adjacent"):
        continue
    df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: x[0] + "," if x.size > 0 else pd.NA)

df["temp"] = (
    df[[f"adjacent_{i}" for i in range(4)]].fillna("").sum(axis=1).str.split(",")
)

# Reorder dataframe to move nan values to the most right
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        df["temp"].values.tolist(), index=df.set_index(["x", "y", "value"]).index
    )
    .add_prefix("adjacent_")
    .replace("", pd.NA)
    .dropna(how="all", axis=1)
    .reset_index()
)

# Rename columns
df.columns = ["x", "y", "value"] + [f"adjacent_{i+1}" for i in range(3)]
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   x  y   value adjacent_1 adjacent_2 adjacent_3
0  0  0     red       pink     yellow       <NA>
1  1  0    pink        red      green     orange
2  2  0   green       pink       blue       blue
3  3  0    blue      green     purple       <NA>
4  0  1  yellow        red     orange       <NA>
5  1  1  orange     yellow       pink       blue
6  2  1    blue     orange      green     purple
7  3  1  purple       blue       blue       <NA>
```